# Matlab: Compare indices of 2 arrays and if matched add value to arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a master array with an index in the first column. I would like to match now a few arrays against it by comparing their index (also first column) to the master and if match found add the correspondent value from column 2 to the master array.

I tried with intersect but could not get it to work.

In the master I have basically dates (in number not date format) as an index, the other arrays I want to match against it have also dates in the first row, it should be in most cases shorter but it could be also the case that the array has dates the master does not have.

```
master = [736182; 736183; 736186; 736187; 736188; 736189];

A = [736186  5
     736187  3
     736188  2];

B = [736187  -15
     736188  1
     736189  -12];
```

Desired Result in Master

```
736182   
736183   
736186    5
736187    3   -15
736188    2     1
736189         -12
```

Comment: Can you show a desired input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the [second output of `ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html?refresh=true#outputarg_Locb) to determine the rows in `A` and `B` that correspond to the indices in column 1 of `master`. You can then use this information to grab the relevant rows of `A` and `B` and use them however you need.

```
%// Find the rows in A and B that correspond to the index value in master
[isInA, Aind] = ismember(master(:,1), A(:,1));  
[isInB, Bind] = ismember(master(:,1), B(:,1));

%// Get Column 2 of A and B that corresponds to the index in master 
%// and concatenate them to master. Any values in master that were not
%// found in A or B are replaced by NaN

new_master = [master, nan(size(master, 1), 2)];
new_master(isInA,2) = A(Aind(isInA), 2);
new_master(isInB,3) = B(Bind(isInB), 2);

%// MASTER  A     B
%// 736182  NaN   NaN
%// 736183  NaN   NaN
%// 736186    5   NaN
%// 736187    3   -15
%// 736188    2     1
%// 736189  NaN   -12
```

**Update**

If you need to populate `new_master` inside of a loop you can initialize `new_master` outside of the loop and then fill it as you go through the loop.

```
new_master = [master, nan(size(master, 1), 2)];

for k = 1:N
    A = %// Get new value for A
    B = %// Get new value for B

    %// Do comparisons
    [isInA, Aind] = ismember(master(:,1), A(:,1));
    [isInB, Bind] = ismember(master(:,1), B(:,1));

    new_master(isInA,2) = A(Aind(isInA), 2);
    new_master(isInB,3) = B(Bind(isInB), 2);
end
```

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately the code returns: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.   For the code new_master = [master, A(Aind,2), B(Bind, 2)];

Comment: @Senf This is likely because you have values in `master` that are not present in `A` or `B`. You need to define what you want to do in those cases. Please update your initial question with some example data and an expected output and then I can update my answer to suit that

Comment: In the last row of Aind it returns a 0? Is that the issue?

Comment: @Senf Please see my last comment

Comment: @Senf Should be updated now. Any value that's not present in A or B is replaced by a NaN

Comment: Many thanks, I think the problem is that I go loop and each time at the end this comparison to the master happens. So only at the end of all loops I will know which vales are not in any of the arrays

Comment: @Senf I have added a brief update on how you could do this within a loop